# What is the meaning of “worn” in “There was a little path worn”

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-participles, ambiguity

Meaning of "worn" in the context below

> So quiet did it seem and so lonely, that almost one might think that nothing but the wild red deer, or his fierce enemy the slinking wolf, had ever walked this way since the beginning of the world. There was a little path **worn** among the thick bushes of hazel, dogberry, and traveler's joy, but so narrow was it and so faint that it could well have been **worn** by the slender, fleeting feet of the doe, or even by the hares and rabbits which had their home in a great bank among the roots of a beech nearby.

Is it an adjective? And does it mean: ragged?

Source: The Merry adventures of Rabin Hood.

Answer (score 1):

This word has multiple meanings, the above is the following:

> There was a little path **worn**... - [adjective] an *object* which has been damaged because of continuous use. -[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/worn)

Comment: It seems worth mentioning that _worn_ is the past participle of the verb _to wear_. In "it could well have been worn..." it is used as a verb in the passive voice.

Comment: Also in this context the meaning is **not** _damaged_. It means the path was created by frequent travel. Enough people or animals walked that way, trampling the grass or undergrowth, to generate or _wear_ a path.